# Bulk url status code Expected is (website status code 200, which is working on web ) actual ( status code is Error)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-codes, urlfetch

> try on your own ide for testing the script

[**go to Extension->App script ;also you will find script given below script name :status code ]**

[**question** is every url like google, fb, amazon links are working and showing 200 status but  (page is loading on browser but the status code is showing error on the sheet is there any modifications need to be done to the below code ]

//code start

```
  function getStatusCode(url){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  return response.getResponseCode();
  }
```

//code end

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: foxtel.com.au maybe blocking Google's servers or it's user agent.

Comment: foxtel.com.au if we can access it on browser why cant we get the status code even i tried using aus Vpn but it didn't worked

Comment: The requests are made from Google servers and not your browser.